# ImportError: cannot import name ensure_text I am getting this error while I am connecting to cassandra using cqlsh. Any solution

Tags: cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azureuser/bin/cqlsh-astra/bin/dsecqlsh.py", line 95, in <module>
    import cqlsh  # nopep8
  File "/home/azureuser/bin/cqlsh-astra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 154, in <module>
    from six import StringIO, ensure_text, ensure_str
ImportError: cannot import name ensure_text
```

I am expecting to connect cassandra through cqlsh

Answer (score 0):

You can run the DataStax cqlsh using the old ubuntu 18.04 distro

```
# install docker
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
# install distrobox
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/89luca89/distrobox/main/install | sudo sh
# create a ubuntu 18.04 image
distrobox create --image ubuntu:18.04 --name cqlsh
# enter into a cqlsh
distrobox enter cqlsh
#
# run you cqlsh command
```